# How can I order Wp_Query hierarchically?

Tags: wp-query, order

I have a cpt for which I need to order `Wp_Query` hierarchically...

Example:

Show 1
Episode 1
Episode 2

Show 2
Episode 1
Episode 2

I thought `order_by=parent` would do it, but apparently not so.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Is your custom post type defined as hierarchical like pages? and 2) Are you using as custom taxonomy?

Comment: @belinus ... thanks. CPT is hierarchical, not used as custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use something other than a single WP_Query. You could use `wp_list_pages()` with a custom walker to get your desired structure.

`wp_list_pages` in widget, sidebar, or wherever you want the list to appear:

```
<ul class="cpt-hierarchy"><!-- or whatever class you like -->
<?php
wp_list_pages(array(
    'post_type' => 'cpt', // replace with your cpt's slug
    'title_li' => '', // don't include a title LI
    'post_status' => 'publish', // don't include private/draft/etc.
    'sort_column' => 'post_title', // order by post title
    'walker' => new wpse_hierarchy_walker)
);
?>
</ul>
```

Walker in theme's functions.php:

```
<?php
class wpse_hierarchy_walker extends Walker_page {
    public function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0) {
        if($depth)
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $css_class = array('page_item');
        if(!empty($current_page)) {
            $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
            $children = get_children('post_type=page&post_status=publish&post_parent='.$page->ID);
            if(count($children) != 0) {
                $css_class[] = 'hasChildren';
            }
            if(isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors))
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            if($page->ID == $current_page)
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            elseif($_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent)
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        } elseif($page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts')) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }
        $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );
        if($page->ID == $current_page) {
            $output .= $indent .'<li class="' . $css_class . '">' . $page->post_title;
        } else {
            $output .= $indent .'<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $page->post_title .'</a>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Then using CSS you can indent the children as much as you want. `li.hasChildren ul` will be wrapped around the children.

Comment: I would say turn it into a plugin though. Anything that changes/creates content structure should not be part of the theme and since this walker is dependent on the CPT, both should be rolled into a plugin instead.

Comment: @WebElaine... follow-up - brain-faded earlier. I was using Wp_Query so that I can show title/excerpt/thumbnail... which I can probably do by adapting your code - will look at it later when fresh.

Comment: Yes, you can add those to the walker. Definitely good to look at with maximum brainpower. :)